# JTextArea not displaying text

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, swingworker

In my function for displaying text in textarea,i have written following lines of code but it is not displaying any text

```
        jTextArea1.setText( Packet +"\n" +jTextArea1.getText());
```

I am using swingworker for performing background task,here is my code

```
public class SaveTraffic extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {


public GUI f = new GUI();

@Override
public Void doInBackground() throws IOException {
              //some code
              sendPacket(captor.getPacket().toString()); 
              return null;
             }//end main function

@Override
public void done() {
    System.out.println("I am DONE");

}


public void sendPacket(String Packet) {

 f.showPackets(Packet);
}
```

}

and the following lines of code i have written in my GUI form

```
 public  void showPackets(String Packet) {

 jTextArea1.append( Packet);

}
```

Solution:
         public class SaveTraffic extends SwingWorker {

```
     public GUI f = new GUI();

     @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws IOException {
    f.add(jTextPane1);
   // some code

   publish(captor.getPacket().toString());

   // the method below is calling sendPacket on the background thread
   // which then calls showPackets on the background thread
   // which then appends text into the JTextArea on the background thread
  //sendPacket(captor.getPacket().toString());

    return null;
   }

  @Override
   protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
   for (String text : chunks) {
     jTextPane1.setText(text);
     f.showPackets(text);
   }
  }

  @Override
  public void done() {
   System.out.println("I am DONE");

   }
```

}

Comment: It seems that longer code snippet may be helpful.

Comment: Please give us more information -- enough so that we don't have to all guess.

Comment: In your new code, is your `sendPacket(...)` method call supposed to be `showPackets(...)`? If not, where do you call `showPackets(...)`? You know that `sendPacket(...)` is being called from within your background thread, and if that is where you're trying to write to your JTextArea, then yep, you've got a concurrency issue.

Comment: And 1+ for the edit, we've almost got enough information,... but not quite.

Comment: i call the showPackets() in sendPacket(...) method

Comment: OK, I'm right. This means you're making Swing calls from within the background thread and yours is a concurrency issue. Hang on, and I'll show you a possible solution using publish and process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yours is a very incomplete question, one without enough information to allow an answer, and one that forces us to guess, but based on this line in your original post:

> The function is called continuously ...

I'll guess, and I will bet money that you've got a Swing threading issue. You will probably want to read up on and use a SwingWorker.

Start here to learn about the EDT and SwingWorkers: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Yes, yours is a Swing concurrency issue caused by your making Swing calls from within the background thread. To avoid doing this, you need to export the data from doInBackground and call it on the Swing event thread. One way to to do this is via the publish/process method pair:

```
public class SaveTraffic extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

  public GUI f = new GUI();

  @Override
  public Void doInBackground() throws IOException {

     // some code

     publish(captor.getPacket().toString());

     // the method below is calling sendPacket on the background thread
     // which then calls showPackets on the background thread
     // which then appends text into the JTextArea on the background thread
     //sendPacket(captor.getPacket().toString());

     return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void process(List<String> packetTextList) {
     for (String packetText : packetTextList) {
        sendPacket(packetText); //edit, changed to match your code
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void done() {
     System.out.println("I am DONE");

  }

  public void sendPacket(String Packet) {

     f.showPackets(Packet);
  }
}
```

Check the tutorial I linked to above and the SwingWorker API for more details on this.

Comment: I am using swingworker for other tasks in my code but in my this function where i want to display text in text area,I have just written this one line of code

Comment: @Zara: you still don't tell us enough to be able to give you more than silly wild-@ssed guesses. Why are you not telling us more?

Comment: @Zara: see my last edit for your problem and a possible solution

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks a lot for help but i don't know why my code not allowing me to override process method of swingworker and secondly when i write the publish code line,it says that publish method is not present in your project :(

Comment: Anyways u have given me a right direction of publish and process methods .Thanks

Comment: @Zara: you probably need to change your SwingWorker generic parameters. Note that in my example, the second parameter is not Void but rather is String because this is what publish and process deal with. Please read the SwingWorker tutorial as it's all explained there.

Comment: @Zara, and you're welcome. Also note that I changed the method called within the process method to better match your currently posted code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Followed your code,now i can print all the packets in showpacket() but still unable to display the results in TextArea.TextArea shows nothing

Comment: Then there's another bug, perhaps a misplaced reference. We'll likely need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using setText() use append()

Comment: Which will happen, if he appends, instead of setting the text PLUS the previous text in the box. That's exactly what append does. He is re-inventing the wheel here with that method.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. Thanks for the clarification. I will delete my comment and up-vote you.

Answer (score 2):

Since your code snippet is just too small to give a correct answer I can think of:

1. When you are inside the update of `jTextArea`, `Packet` is null? Can you check that.
2. While calling this method is `jTextArea` has any text on it ? If none and `Packet` is null you wont see any result.

Edit: As per comment:

To append text use [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29), also read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Though I would expect `setText` to show the text atleast first time, see below a bare minimum example code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestJTextArea {
    static void init() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        frame.add(textField,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setText(textField.getText());
            }
        });
        frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        init();
    }
}
```

And with that I also agree with @Hovercraft Full Of Eels that you may have a Swing threading issue, or just use append to append text

Comment: When i take the print out of Packet,it displays a complete string continuously...