# How to get JScrollPane to Update during long process

Tags: java, swing

I have a JScrollPane which contains a JTextArea object. In this particular application, the JTextArea is serving as a "process console" so that someone can see what is happening with a long-running process. My code looks like this:

```
JTextArea console;

...

// Initializes the console panel, including creation of the JTextArea and JScrollPane
private void initializePanel() {
    JPanel consolePanel = new JPanel();
    ...
    console = new JTextArea();
    console.setEnabled(false);
    textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(console);
    ...
}

// Appends an incoming message to the console
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object consoleMessage) {
    console.append(consoleMessage + "\n");
    console.update(console.getGraphics());
}
```

The problem I am running into is that my JScrollPane doesn't start with a scroll bar. As text gets appended to the underlying JTextArea, it goes off the bottom of the JScrollPane. Unfortunately, the scroll bar doesn't appear until the long-running process is complete. At that point, the scroll bar suddenly appears and the view jumps to they very end of the JTextArea.

As such, the application looks like it is frozen as further messages are outside of the current viewport of the JScrollPane.

I have tried different combinations of code to try to get the JSrollPane to repaint every time a message is written to it, but no such luck. The JTextArea gets the messages and they are printed immediately upon receipt - it's really the JScrollPane not adding the scroll bar right away that is being problematic.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running this "process" in another thread?

Comment: I have not, but that's not a bad idea.

Comment: Remember to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` when updating GUI from another thread...

Comment: You want a `SwingWorker` that invokes `append()` on the `JTextArea`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10674913/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mrpyo's comment was spot on. I spawned off a second thread (using SwingWorker) to do the long-running process and that frees up the user thread to do UI updates.

One thing I had to add was to force the JScrollPane to always scroll to the bottom. I did that by simply calling

```
console.selectAll(); // console is my JTextArea object
```

Because my JTextArea object is not enabled, calling selectAll() doesn't actually cause anything to be selected, but it does have the side effect of scrolling the JScrollPane to the end. It's not an elegant solution so, if anyone has something better, I'm all ears - but it works.

Thanks, mrpyo!

The link provided by trashgod led me here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

...which turned into a great resource on how to do this concurrency correctly.

Comment: I would use the [`setCaretPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition(int)) method

Comment: @Robin: Thanks. I changed my implementation to use setCaretPosition and am much happier with that, as it doesn't feel like I'm using a side-effect to get my desired behavior.