# Do multiple tasks while running code in actionperformed java

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

Let's say i have a listener attached to a button. When i press this button, actionPerformed is called and i set a **label** as visible. Then the `calculate()` method runs(which has some really long calculations inside it and it takes time). Then i wanna print the results with the `show()` method.

Thing is that i know for a fact that the **label** will be set as **visible** after all the code inside `actionPerformed` will be executed.

So my question is : How should i set the `calculate` method to run on background? Threads? SwingTimer? SwingWorker? I haven't found an ideal way yet.

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calculateLbl.setVisible(true);
        calculate();           
        show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of Swing concurrency: When calculate() is called on the Swing event thread, the long-running code hampers the event thread, preventing it from painting to the JLabel. The solution is to run calculate in a background thread, and then be notified when it is done. When notification occurs, call `show()`. A SwingWorker would work great for this since it comes with its own notification mechanism.

e.g.,

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    calculateLbl.setVisible(true);
    new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        public Void doInBackground() throws Exception{
            calculate(); // this is run in a background thread
                         // take care that calculate makes no Swing calls
            return null;
        }

        protected void done() {
            show();  // this is run on the Swing event thread
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Caveat: code not tested/compiled/nor run.

A problem with the above code is that it does not handle any exceptions that might be thrown within the calculate method, and a cleaner better way to do this is to create a SwingWorker variable, attach a PropertyChangeListener to it, and when its SwingWorker.StateValue is SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE, call `get()` on the SwingWorker and handle any possible exceptions there.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, the sample code helped me understand how to start and now i can edit it more and go on.

Comment: Could you tell me a way that i can call `show()` to print results in the frame while `calculate()` is running? For example it could run every 100 times of the inside the `calculate` loop.

Comment: @breathtaker: Have a look at using the publish/process within your SwingWorker, including looking at the [SwingWorker Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) as well as searching this site. For example, have a look at [my related answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a522444%20swingworker%20publish%20process) that can easily be found.

Comment: @breathtaker: In particular, please check out these answer links: [answer link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089929/522444), [answer link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32363814/522444), [answer link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10674913/522444).